# PowerShell Default value not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to feed my function with some variables and when no variable is given it should use a default value of 30 for `OlderThanDays`. For one reason or another this is not working out as I'd expected.

I fixed my problem in the ForEach loop by using `if($_.B -ne $null) {$OlderThanDays=$_.B} else {$OlderThanDays="30"}` But I don't think this is best practice. Can anyone tell me why `[Int]$OlderThanDays=30` isn't working?

Problem: When adding a line in my csv-file without defining the `OlderThanDays`variable, the default of 30 days is not used and the files are just deleted...

Thank you for your help.

CSV file:

```
# Correct input formats are:
#
# ServerName, LocalPath, OlderThanDays
# Ex: server, E:\SHARE\Target, 10 
# Ex: server, E:\CBR\SHARE\Target
#
# UNC-Path, OlderThanDays
# Ex: \\domain\SHARE\Target, 20
# Ex: \\domain\Target
#
# If no 'OlderThanDays' is provided, a default of 30 days will be used
# Commenting out can be done with '#'
# ______________________________________________________________________

SERVER1, E:\SHARE\Target
\\domain\SHARE\Target2
```

Full script:

```
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
$ImportFile = "S:\Input\Scheduled Task\Auto_Clean.csv"
$Password = cat "S:\Input\pwd.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force
$UserName = "domain\me"
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
# Scriptblock for running the function in a job
$JobCall = {
    # Function that removes files older than x days in all subfolders
    Function Delete-OldFiles {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [String]$Target,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
        [Int]$OlderThanDays=30,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]
        [String]$Server,
        [switch]$CleanFolders
          )

    #__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # Create logfile 
    $TempDate = (get-date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    $TempFolderPath = $Target -replace '\\','_'
    $TempFolderPath = $TempFolderPath -replace ':',''
    $TempFolderPath = $TempFolderPath -replace ' ',''

    $script:LogFile = "\\DEUSTHEIDIT02\Log\Scheduled Task\Auto_Clean\$Server - $TempFolderPath - $TempDate.log"

    #__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # Check the version of PowerShell
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge "3") {

        # PowerShell 3+ Remove files older than (FASTER)
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -File | 
        Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | 

            ForEach {
            $Item = $_.FullName
            Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                # Log succes/failure
                $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
                if (Test-Path $Item) { 
                    "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
                } 
                else { 
                    "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item" 
                }  
            } | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append -Verbose}

    Else {               

        # PowerShell 2 Remove files older than
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse | 
        Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | 

            ForEach {
            $Item = $_.FullName
            Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                # Log succes/failure
                $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()   
                if (Test-Path $Item) { 
                    Write-Host "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
                   "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
                } 
                else { 
                      Write-Host "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item"
                     "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item"
                }  
            } | Out-File $LogFile -Append } 

    #__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
        # Switch -CleanFolders deletes empty folders older than x days
        if ($CleanFolders) {

            # Check the version of PowerShell
            if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge "3") {

                # PowerShell 3+ Remove empty folders older than (FASTER)
                Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -Force -Directory  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | 
                Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -File) -eq $null } | 

                    ForEach {
                    $Item = $_.FullName
                    Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                        # Log succes/failure
                        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
                        if (Test-Path $Item) { 
                            "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)" 
                        } 
                        else { 
                            "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item" 
                        }  
                    } | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append
            }     

            else {

                # PowerShell 2 Remove empty folders older than 
                Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | 
                Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | 

                    ForEach {
                    $Item = $_.FullName
                    Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                        # Log succes/failure
                        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
                        if (Test-Path $Item) { 
                            Write-Host "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
                            "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)" 
                        } 
                        else { 
                            Write-Host "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item"
                            "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item" 
                        }  
                    } |  Out-File $LogFile -Append 
            } 
        }
    }
# Lact command of the ScriptBlock: Call the magic to happen
Delete-OldFiles $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] -CleanFolders:$args[3]
}

#__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
# Read input file and ignore all lines starting with #
$File = (Import-Csv -Path $ImportFile -Header "A", "B", "C", "D" | Where { $_.A -NotLike "#*" } )

#__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
# If the UNC Path is provided we will run the script locally else it wil be run on the remote server as a job
Foreach ($_ in $File) {

    # Define input format & default values
    if ($_.A -like "\\*") {
        $Server="UNC"
        $Target=$_.A
        $OlderThanDays=$_.B
        $CleanFolders=$_.C
    }
    else {
        $Server=$_.A
        $Target=$_.B
        $OlderThanDays=$_.C
        $CleanFolders=$_.D        
    }

            # Call the scriptblock with the function to run locally or on the remote server
            if ($Server -eq "UNC")
            {
                Write-Host "UNC Path detected: $Target, $OlderThanDays" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server) -Name DelFiles
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Local path detected: $Server, $Target, $OlderThanDays" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$Password            
                Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server) -ComputerName "$Server.domain" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -AsJob -JobName DelFiles

                # Delete empty folders: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, $true) -ComputerName "$Server.domain" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -AsJob -JobName DelFiles
            }  
}
```

Comment: How do you execute the function, ie what does your `Delete-OldFiles param1 param2.. etc` look like?

Comment: You haven't really specified what you mean with "not working". Could you please elaborate on the problems you observe which makes you state that it is not working? Furthermore, you have at attribute on the `$OlderThanDays` parameter saying that the parameter is mandatory, so the caller will always have to specify this parameter.

Comment: I've updated the first post with the full script. Even when changing the variable `OlderThanDays`to not mandatory, it's still not taken into account the default value of 30.

Comment: @Raf The function is called with the scriptblock `CallJob`below in the script. When using the `Start-Job`and `Invoke-Command`Cmdlets.

Comment: @DarkLite1 The problem is that you **are** specifying the `$OlderThanDays` parameter in your call. If you want to dynamically determine the parameters you want to supply to a cmdlet you should probably read the help section about splatting; just run the command `Get-Help about_Splatting`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter can't be both Mandatory and have default value. Former is checked first, and if it's set to `$true`, than default value is simply ignored. If you want to make sure that users can't specify empty value, just use `[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]` validation, and make parameter optional.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your suggestion of making the variable `OlderThanDays` not mandatory, but it's still not using 30 days as a default value when I don't provide the number of days in my csv-file. See updated first post for the full script.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar problem. After months keeping a module with personal functions for day-to-day activities making extensive use of default values and, in many cases, mandatory parameters with initialized default values, suddenly my functions stopped working. 
After writing a new one, calling it with explicit parameters would result in the parameters values being empty in the function execution context.
After restarting powershell console for some times I decided to reboot the machine, and everything went back to normal. Go figure.